# CSS element width to increase in steps

Tags: css

> UPDATE: Please see image at the bottom of question.

So I have a set of inputs and checkboxes, and it is now required that the checkboxes and text inputs align; so I want to "step" the size of the inputs.

The checkboxes are fine and have a width of 160px, horizontally lining up as many as possible on the device screen width, but I need some way of getting the size of the text boxes to also fit the same sizing such as:

**Overall container size only matters in that textbox container size is 76% of it**

> Textbox container: 608px 
>   Textbox Size: 480px (160 x 3) 
>   Checkboxes in row: 3
>
> Textbox container: 532px  
>   Textbox Size: 480px (160 x 3)  
>   Checkboxes in row: 3
>
> Textbox container: 380px
>   Textbox Size: 320px (160 x 2)  
>   Checkboxes in row: 2
>
> Textbox container: 304px  
>   Textbox Size: 160px (160 x 1)  
>   Checkboxes in row: 1

**To be clear**
If the container width is `380px` then the textbox within would need to act like the inline-block checkboxes and only be `320px` wide because the next *step* would be `320+160 = 480px` which would be wider than the container.

So that the width of the textbox increases in "steps" equal to the width of the checkboxes (160px, but this would be hardcoded as it won't change once set).

Below is the code I have at the moment; and really I'm not sure where to being with this problem. Is there a certain phrase to search for, a certain wording to find out possible solutions.

Also; while the HTML is in a table format; I don't think that should be too important in this instance as it's only a single cell container for the `<input>` elements just like a div, etc.

```css
.catitem {
    width: 160px;
    display: inline-block;
    border:1px solid #090;
}
table {
    width: 100%
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table tr:nth-of-type(2n+1) {
  background-color:#eaeaea;
}
 table tbody tr td:first-of-type {
    width: 24%;
    min-width: 55px;
    font-weight: bold;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-left: 1rem;
    }
table tr td:nth-of-type(2) input[type="text"] {
  width:82%;            /* THIS bit needs changing */
  max-width:500px;      /*                         */
 }
```

```html
<table>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Title:</td>
                    <td><input name="title" id="title" maxlength="12" placeholder="" type="text">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>First Name:</td>
                    <td><input name="fname" id="fname" maxlength="64" required="" type="text"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Surname:</td>
                    <td><input name="sname" id="sname" maxlength="64" required="" type="text"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Postcode:</td>
                    <td><input name="pcode" id="pcode" maxlength="10" required="" type="text"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top">Categories:</td>
                    <td>
    <label class="catitem">
        <input name="cats[]" value="chs" type="checkbox">
        Coach
    </label>
    <label class="catitem">
        <input name="cats[]" value="exm" type="checkbox">
        Ex-members
    </label>
    <label class="catitem">
        <input name="cats[]" value="fam" type="checkbox">
        Family Membership
    </label>
    <label class="catitem">
        <input name="cats[]" value="fos" type="checkbox">
        Friends
    </label>
    <label class="catitem">
        <input name="cats[]" value="ldy" type="checkbox">
        Ladies
    </label>
    <label class="catitem">
        <input name="cats[]" value="spr" type="checkbox">
        Sponsor
    </label>
              </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><input value="Add Member" type="submit"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
```

## Image Explanation:

[image]

So the 1 Step width will be on show when the container width is less than 2 steps (160 x 2); and the two step width will be on show when the container element is less than 3 steps wide (160 x 3), etc.

In the image above all boxes should be the width of the **Postcode** box, and when the container shrinks they would reduce down to the width of the **title** input box, but *would not use any inbetween widths*.

Comment: Have you investigated flexbox:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

I'm not exactly sure what you are asking for but it might help. It's pretty good for layout type issues IME.

Comment: @swervo I have some experience of flexbox, but can you illustrate flexbox using step increments as requested? Cheers

Comment: use display:flex and flex-wrap:wrap,then give the textboxes size 160px. It will align the textboxes in the container according to the size and wrap the extra textbox to next line.

Comment: Not really sure what you want this to look like eventually, at the different sizes. Plus, _“Overall container size: 800px”_ sounds like you might want the as of yet not really existing element queries, instead of viewport-based media queries. But in any case, I think without the table this might be a lot easier (at least if you don’t want to explicitly specify the width for all cases.)

Comment: If you know breakpoints and sizes why not use media queries?

Comment: If I understands your question correctly then here is the demo - https://jsfiddle.net/zh9q4zpj/

Comment: @vishugosain your example doesn't seem to fit what's going on.... the example looks like the checkboxes which work fine. I need the width of the element can be `160px` or `320px` but not anything inbetween

Comment: @CBroe tbh the "overall container size" may be a needless detail of the current layout and outside the scope of my actual question. I will edit....

Comment: @Pete meh this could be a solution but would be undynamic. If the checkbox size changes I'd have to remember to edit all media queries... `:-/`  . Seeing if there's an alternative solution

Answer (score 1):

For a more dynamic result than Media Queries, you could try structuring this using CSS calc(): https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp

So you'd have something like width: (100% - 160px); for each container and have a max-width for the container set either fixed (if you're ok  with those) or use Bootstrap or similar to set a max-width based on columns in the page.

Comment: I had considered calc but can't see how it would work in "steps". CSS sizing seems to only work in steps of "1" rather than ,say, "160"

Comment: I figure you could create a set of parent elements that would control this for you 'dynamically'. For example, your whole table would be 480px, and then you could use Boostratp/any grid framework to set a container inside as 76% max-width to control your textbox and checkbox displays.
In short, I think you'd have 3 containers; one overall (480px), one for your form with textbox containers inside (100%), and one specifically for your textbox container (calc(480px - 76%)).

Comment: I'd be curious if you can illustrate this in your answer? I have updated my question btw too. Cheers

Comment: Sorry for the delay, figured it's easier if I just try it in pen instead (tables aren't exactly my forte). I believe this is what you're looking for:
https://codepen.io/ashwinbsd/pen/mxRYRB

It sets a max-width, min-width, and then uses calc for the rest. Also used max-width separately for #title, #fname, and #pcode as I believe that's in your drawing (See bottom of Pen CSS)

Comment: Thanks for the effort, that looks promising but unfortunately doesn't do the "step", see [my screen shot here](https://ibb.co/jbzMAH) where the Surname/Postcode lines are 1.5 Checkboxes wide. `:-/`

Comment: Yeah close but no banana. I tried with media queries too and one always changes before the other. If it were a <div>, you could put the elements you want to resize together all in one, so maybe that's worth the effort if you / your client is really into it.